# HTTP Basic Authentication in PayPal Webhook URLs

Tags: ruby, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, basic-authentication

(Added: For this question, assume operations on the PayPal API are working and authenticated.)

Do PayPal Webhooks support URLs with HTTP Basic authentication credentials, so the following would create a valid webhook that used the given credentials `foo:secret`?

```
webhook_attrs = {
  # NOTE the URL has HTTP Basic credentials of
  # user is 'foo' and password is 'secret':
  url: 'https://foo:secret@example.com/paypal_events',
  event_types: [
      { name: 'PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.CREATED' },
      { name: 'PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.VOIDED' }
  ]
}
webhook = PayPal::SDK::REST::Webhook.new(webhook_attrs)
if webhook.create && webhook.error.nil?
  p "Created webhook:", webhook
else
  p "Failed to create webhook:", webhook.error, webhook
end
```

Comment: You should probably read the docs https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/ about how to make a first call . You need an access token to pass in URL as a parameter or header. In your case You can put it in the URL but You have to go through all the steps first..get an clientid and a clientsecret and exchange those for a access token just like in the examples from the docs. After that You can make any request using the access token

Comment: Thanks Rada, and apologies for the question not being clear. The API auth is working correctly. This question is about a different aspect of the API. I've added clarification to the question and will add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal Webhooks do not support HTTP Basic authentication (at time of writing).

Trying to create a Webhook with a URL including HTTP Basic credentials will fail with the following error:

```
{
  "name" => "VALIDATION_ERROR",
  "details" => [ { "field" => "url", "issue" => "Not a valid webhook URL" } ], 
  "message" => "Invalid data provided",
  "information_link" => "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/#errors"
}
```

For developers hoping to do this, a couple of suggestions:

1. Ask PayPal to support this (may be worth mentioning Stripe Webhooks support HTTP Basic Authentication)
2. As a workaround, consider including a long, random secret token in the URL query string instead as an authentication check. For this to be worthwhile the URL must be HTTPS. Beware timing and length attacks in the code that checks the token, a simple `==` equality check is vulnerable to timing attacks. See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d66e7835bea9505f7003e5038aa19b6ea95ceea1/activesupport/lib/active_support/security_utils.rb#L22 for more on timing and length attacks.

Answer (score 0):

We know that PayPal Webhooks do not support HTTP Basic authentication ,
But we have one solution for that kind of issue.
We need one live server [without HTTP Basic authentication] so we can setup on PHP file for webhook URL In paypal app.

1. Create one PHP file on live server called `paypalWebhook.php`.
   below are the code for this file.

   ```
   $body = @file_get_contents('php://input');

   $url = 'https://foo:secret@example.com/paypal_events';

   //open connection
   $ch = curl_init();
   //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

   //execute post
   $result = curl_exec($ch);

   //close connection
   curl_close($ch);
   ```
2. Now can setup Webhook URL like this : `https://{live-server}/paypalWebhook.php`

Now you can able to get all post values via live server to you devlopment[HTTP Basic authentication server].

Comment: Where is the point? You just proxy all incoming requests by PHP script. There is no additional security benefits.